# Finding all Nix build time dependencies, including bootstrapping ones

Tags: nix

I'm trying to set up a Nix cache containing all the store paths needed to build a simple derivation. The goal is for this to work on an empty store, with no cache misses so I don't have to hit cache.nixos.org at all. I'm having trouble because Nix seems to download a bunch of extra bootstrapping stuff, apparently to help with fetching.

For example, consider this derivation:

```hs
# empty_store_test_simple.nix
with { inherit (import <nixpkgs> {}) fetchFromGitHub; };

(fetchFromGitHub {
  owner = "codedownio";
  repo = "templates";
  rev = "ba68b83d25d2b74f5475521ac00de3bbb884c983";
  sha256 = "sha256-LNTi1ZBEsThmGWK53U9Na1j5DKHljcS42/PRXj97p6s=";
})
```

If I build this on an empty store with `--dry-run`, I see the following:

```
λ nix build --impure --store ~/experimental-store --substituters https://cache.nixos.org/ --dry-run -f ./empty_store_test_simple.nix
this derivation will be built:
  /nix/store/jr55kq3kk6va95rvjcdyn5jmh059007p-source.drv
these 48 paths will be fetched (24.52 MiB download, 121.41 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/02bfycjg1607gpcnsg8l13lc45qa8qj3-libssh2-1.10.0
  /nix/store/0fi0432kdh46x9kbngnmz2y7z0q68cdz-xz-5.2.5-bin
  /nix/store/0rizskpri8d8qawx6qjqcnvlxcvzr1bm-keyutils-1.6.3-lib
  /nix/store/1l4r0r4ab3v3a3ppir4jwiah3icalk9d-zlib-1.2.11
  /nix/store/1xyz8jwyg9rya2f7gs549c7n2ah378v6-stdenv-linux
  /nix/store/3h4a92kysiw3s3rvbsa6a2nys3lf8f8v-libkrb5-1.18
  /nix/store/3ibnw61rlgj2lj5hycy2dn3ybpq7wapm-libev-4.33
  /nix/store/5qbrz5fimkbywws73vaim8allyh8kjy5-nghttp2-1.43.0-bin
  /nix/store/67x6kxbanrqafx3hg7pb3bc83i3d1v3f-gzip-1.11
  /nix/store/6irxz4fbf1d1ac7wvdjf8cqb3sgmnvg8-zlib-1.2.11-dev
  /nix/store/71pachqc22wlvf3xjhwjh2rqbl6l3ngg-diffutils-3.8
  /nix/store/9mp06ni69a44dmrjhn28mn15brdry52w-gnused-4.8
  /nix/store/9ppi191zsi7zvynkm8vy2bi22lci9iwg-bzip2-1.0.6.0.2
  /nix/store/c9f15p1kwm0mw5p13wsnvd1ixrhbhb12-gcc-10.3.0-lib
  /nix/store/d1n274a607fmqdgr7888nq19hdsj7av0-openssl-1.1.1l-bin
  /nix/store/d8p27w4d21xs6svkaf3ij60lsw243rn2-openssl-1.1.1l-dev
  /nix/store/fdbwa5jrijn0yzwl8l4xdxa0l5daf5j6-curl-7.79.1
  /nix/store/fvprxgcxf4px865gdjd81fbwnxcjrg41-coreutils-9.0
  /nix/store/gf6j3k1flnhayvpnwnhikkg0s5dxrn1i-openssl-1.1.1l
  /nix/store/gmnh4jfjhx83aggwgwzcnrwmpmqr8fwf-gnutar-1.34
  /nix/store/gmzhclix3kzhir5jmmwakwhpg6j5zwf1-acl-2.3.1
  /nix/store/h0b8ajwz9lvw3a3vqrf41cxrhlx9dz7p-nghttp2-1.43.0-lib
  /nix/store/h7srws2r1nalsih91lrm0hfhhar14jzm-libkrb5-1.18-dev
  /nix/store/h97sr1q1rpv1ry83031q51jbkba7q0m4-bzip2-1.0.6.0.2-bin
  /nix/store/ihscadskdrvwc9dvbirff51lr70cphjj-curl-7.79.1-bin
  /nix/store/ikvp5db9hygc14da45lvxi1c9b4ylna9-pcre-8.44
  /nix/store/ilszk5f0zcv8lifkixg47ja1f2lsgxkd-nghttp2-1.43.0-dev
  /nix/store/k0qa3rjifblr2vrgx4g54a59zxlfhg90-xz-5.2.5
  /nix/store/kd14wd2wfmb56zpv5y71yq2lqs11l06k-attr-2.5.1
  /nix/store/ksqy6mszsld4z3w8ybxa2vkjf5cqxw3f-c-ares-1.17.2
  /nix/store/l0wlqpbsvh1pgvhcdhw7qkka3d31si7k-bash-5.1-p8
  /nix/store/lhambyc1v2c7qzzr5sq7p449xs1j6pg8-gnugrep-3.7
  /nix/store/lypy3bif096j0qc1divwa87gdvv3r575-curl-7.79.1-dev
  /nix/store/p12km8psjlmvbmi52wb9r6gfykqxcdnd-libssh2-1.10.0-dev
  /nix/store/pkpynsyxm8c38z4m8ngv52c7v8vhkr2h-unzip-6.0
  /nix/store/prq96vz3ywk955nnxlr7s892wf5qvbr0-mirrors-list
  /nix/store/psqacrv7k5fxz6mdiawc28sxcdchb4c9-ed-1.17
  /nix/store/qbdsd82q5fyr0v31cvfxda0n0h7jh03g-libunistring-0.9.10
  /nix/store/qzr7r4w5gm5m20afn2wz4vlv7ah4sr89-gnumake-4.3
  /nix/store/r5niwjr8r8qags2bzv9z583r9vajxag3-patchelf-0.13
  /nix/store/rnx655nq2qs53yb5arv2gapa91r1wsbn-findutils-4.8.0
  /nix/store/scz4zbxirykss3hh5iahgl39wk9wpaps-libidn2-2.3.2
  /nix/store/sqn31ly001033hsz0dpxwcsay5qdbk2w-gawk-5.1.1
  /nix/store/vslsa0l17xjcrdgm2knwj0z5hlvf73m7-perl-5.34.0
  /nix/store/x6pz7c0ffcd6kxzc8m1rflvqmdbjiihh-nghttp2-1.43.0
  /nix/store/yj11v0gdjqli4nzax4x48xjnh9y36b2q-curl-7.79.1-man
  /nix/store/z56jcx3j1gfyk4sv7g8iaan0ssbdkhz1-glibc-2.33-56
  /nix/store/zjm4xv4nr872mdhvv3j22bzb08rgf1hk-patch-2.7.6
```

However, I can't find all these paths by using the means I would expect:

```
λ nix repl empty_store_test_simple.nix
nix-repl> :b with import <nixpkgs> {}; closureInfo { rootPaths = [inputDerivation]; } 

This derivation produced the following outputs:
  out -> /nix/store/1iqm7sr2rr6i5njnfxlqqyzi567mb4cz-closure-info
```

```
λ cat /nix/store/1iqm7sr2rr6i5njnfxlqqyzi567mb4cz-closure-info/store-paths
/nix/store/icvdinlsgl6y2kxk9wzkj82a53jgpdlm-source
```

I would expect to see ~48 paths here, but I only see 1! How can I get all the build-time dependencies indicated by the dry run? I've seen this kind of issue in the past when IFD is present, could there be some going on in Nixpkgs?

Answer (score 3):

If you build your derivation and store it in your own Nix cache that should work; Nix shouldn't need to get the build-time dependencies of that thing, it can just download the result (i.e. the source code you're fetching) from your cache.

If you want to get the build-time dependencies anyway, try:

```
nix-store -qR $(nix-instantiate test.nix)
```

I think this will get you one step closer but it's not a complete solution.  You'd probably need to build all the derivations in this list or something.